# Examples of systems conforming the Lorenz Attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Might sound like a trivial question but would you please show me some examples of real systems conforming the Lorenz Attractor?

It can be any kind of system, just a little list. It can be a system arising from Economical, Social, Biological or Physical matters.

Answer (score 6):

The chaotic waterwheel! It was literately build to physically realise the Lorenz equations (see [DIY version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7A_rl-DAmUE) and [Harvard version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iNCfNBEJHo)). A nice discussion about it can be found in the [book by Strogatz](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nonlinear-Dynamics-Chaos-Applications-nonlinearity/dp/0738204536).